# inner joins and query uptimization

Tags: sql, sqlplus

the following query produces the desired result.

```
  SELECT client.client_code,client.client_name,dealing_record.transaction_number,
transaction_type.transaction,payment_status.status,payment_record.Amount_settled,
payment_record.payment_date
  FROM client inner Join payment_record on payment_record.client_id= client.client_id
        inner join dealing_record on 
           dealing_record.dealing_record_id=payment_record.dealing_id
        inner join payment_status on 
            payment_record.payment_status_id=payment_status.payment_status_id
        inner Join transaction_type on 
            dealing_record.transaction_type_id=transaction_type.transaction_type_id
     WHERE status='pending settlement' AND payment_date  BETWEEN '07-Nov-2010' AND 
                  '17-Nov-2013';
```

is there another way this can be done with lesser inner joins?

Comment: That really depends on your database structure. If the query is slow make sure you've got the correct indexes required for fast joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best for optimization is to take a look to the execution plan.

The execution plan will tell when the query is making use of an index or not, and with that information you can take action an change your index structure.

Look at the information in this question

[Optimizing Execution Plans for Parameterized T-SQL Queries Containing Window Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635531/optimizing-execution-plans-for-parameterized-t-sql-queries-containing-window-fun)