# Running SQL query with options(recompile) always faster

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan, parameter-sniffing

this is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864934/option-recompile-is-always-faster-why), though I think my example is a bit more in depth and I would appreciate more definite answers.
I'm trying to understand why running the simple query with `option(recompile)` performs better.

```
DECLARE @p9 nvarchar(4000)
SET @p9=N'Alex%'

SELECT ContactId as CandidateId
FROM Candidate
            WHERE
                (
                    @p9 IS NULL
                    OR
                    Forename LIKE @p9
                    OR 
                    PreferredName LIKE @p9
                    OR
                    Surname LIKE @p9
                )
```

When running without `option(recompile)` (no matter how many times I run it)

```
(1166 row(s) affected)
Table 'Candidate'. Scan count 5, logical reads 9762, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

[image: Execution plan with no recompile option specified]

The very same query but `option(recompile)` added in the end

```
(1166 row(s) affected)
Table 'Candidate'. Scan count 3, logical reads 18, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

[image: Execution plan with no recompile option specified]

If I do NOT use variables in the query, but constants instead, then all is fine. I presume it is to do with parameter sniffing, but the question is WHY?
Also what would be the drawbacks of leaving `option(recompile)` for production code?

I also done some diagnostic tests running the query from within the application, and is seems with `option(recompile)` it is always faster results.

**Update**: running `exec sp_updatestats` has no effect and select with `option(recompile)` still performs times better.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: were you planning on adding more information to your question?

Comment: What would you think am I lacking in my question? Schema?

Comment: @MitchWheat, my main question is WHY `option(recompile)` has this impact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Option(recompile)` generates a new plan based on the current statistics, at the expense of compiling a new plan. If your statistics are up to date then 99 times out of 100, you will get an optimal plan (rather than a cached query plan which might not be appropriate for the particular set of parameters you passed in, compared to when the plan was cached. This is termed parameter sniffing)

> "Also what would be the drawbacks of leaving option(recompile) for
>   production code?"

That's fine for a reporting query, but would be a bad idea for a query running many times per second, since the cost of recompiling the plan each time could likely outweigh the cost of actually executing the query!

Also, be aware that Using `Option(recompile)` has the drawback that the procedure won't show up in the relevant DMV's.

Comment: Table statistics are up to date prior running the query

Comment: Well, I ran the update stats (also rebuilt all the indexes, etc.) on a table before running the query and I work on the isolated DB with no one else using it.