# How to improve SQL Server query performance in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I have a large table  and would like to know if it's possible to improve performance for queries.

Running a simple query takes several minutes. See the execution plan below:
https://files.fm/down.php?cf&i=pxgp25tr&n=ep.sqlplan

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016, and I have this stored procedure:

How can I improve the performance of the procedure above?

This is my execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1m43JclQ

Is there a way to improve the select performance?

Comment: I don't have time to make this a complete answer right now, but make your table variables temp tables instead.

Comment: Is the large table you mentioned `DbsTrade`? How many rows? You might experiment with columnstore and perhaps a tabular model to maximize performance of large aggregations..

Comment: About 500000 rows

Comment: Thanks for your help, 
I am weak in sql can you give me some hints... please.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for a better way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1m43JclQ

Answer (score 3):

I would add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`:

```
SET @SQL = @Pre + @Select + @SQL + @GroupBy
=>
SET @SQL = @Pre + @Select + @SQL + @GroupBy + ' OPTION(RECOMPILE)';
```

I would use this clause to generate execution plan and/or cardinality estimations for dynamic SQL every time(it is some kind of report so I assume that the overhead shouldn't be too high). [More info: OPTION (RECOMPILE) is Always Faster; Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20865349/5070879)

It's a good practice to end every statement with semicolon.

Comment: You should explain why you think this will help. (e.g. improve cardinality estimates of the table variables) rather than leaving it as a mysterious incantation.

Comment: I added Option(Recompile) but it steel slow.